# How can I get Elastic IP/host which KIbana is connected to

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Through Kibana interface, how can I get Elastic IP/host?
I mean, the Elastic host which kibana is connected to.
Is that even possible? i'm struggling on that for hours and I got nothing :(

*P.S: Not sure if this question is off-topic and it should be on dba.stackexchange.com*

Answer (score 0):

The address may not the real elastic server address even though you can get the config from elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200". It may a gateway address.

Basically, I do not think there is a way to get the address by API.

Comment: It does not matter if it is a proxy IP, server behind anoter server...I have access to a managed (not by me) Kibana and I would like to get the elasticsearch which kibana is connect to

Comment: Basically, I do not think there is a way to get the address by API.

Answer (score 0):

From Dev Tools interface you can do: GET /_cat/nodes?v